# DDD: When application services need to be "tracked"

Tags: domain-driven-design

Forgive me if the question title is not very clear, as I really don't know how to explain this very well. I'll try.

I'm modelling a domain where I have an AR called Point. I can do certain actions on that Point that modify its state. These are implemented within the AR class or through some domain service. Up to here everything seems to be fine for me.

The problem comes when I have long running processes on a Point. I want to do specific stuff with the single execution of a process, such as monitoring its state, pausing, canceling, retrying, etc. and also to have views that aggregate these processes execution. To me this would seem as part of another context (BC). Is this really a separate context? Is just some sort of behavior that should be part of a framework?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for sagas that sovrintend step by step your *long process.*

> A saga is a long-lived transaction managed by a coordinator. Sagas are
>   initiated by an event, sagas orchestrates events, and sagas maintain
>   the state of the overall transaction. They are designed to manage the
>   complexity of a distributed transaction without locking and immediate
>   consistency. They manage state, and track compensations that are
>   required if a partial failure occurs.

Take a look [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/), [here](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/saga.html) and [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/cs711/2002fa/reading/sagas.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the saga pattern, but in this case each saga would need to be actual entities in another BC. My problem is how can I have these application services that are sometimes cross-contexts without breaking service autonomy.